# Bridging the gap between _gaq.push and gtag

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, gtag.js, google-analytics-4, analytics.js

Looking more for some fresh ideas to help me troubleshoot the below problem than solving any coding issues (which may come next).

Creating a similar site to an existing one that uses all previous GA tech (analytics.js, _gaq.push, Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest(), etc) and provides all the easy data needed for my simple GA reports (i.e. page views by date and location).

However, not quite ready to bite off the whole enchilada (GTAGMgr, GA4, and such) so created dual Properties (UA and GA) as many forums have recommended when making the transition.

Setup the website same as the active [UA] site but using the gtag.js (per the Property Tracking Code snippet provided in ADMIN) vs the analytics.js code.  Created View(s), new Service Account for the "user", an API Map Key for the Google Map Charts, and any other pieces I could find.

Have the GTAG.JS setup on each page and added any special page tracking via gtag('event', 'page view', {...}) but letting the default page view still occur as well.

Page view hits are coming through as expected EXCEPT the page views locations (City, State, Country, Region) are not being populated.  All that comes thru is the "not set" for any location.  Ironically, the old analytics.js code was still active initially and location data was being populated.

Would think if gtag.js is collecting standard page view info for the configured Property, that location data would be there as well.  Am sure it is but possibly the older getReport calls need tweaking.  No doubt I probably have a something not quite right but if REALTIME data shows usage, page views, etc. AND my GA Report calls are working, would think location data would be there too.

Any brainstorming ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you,
LarryG

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER ... the EZ Button ... my code and calls were correct using old and [semi] new way.  The majority of the problems were McAfee VPN kicking in.  It is set to turn on with reboot and I do not always remember to turn it off.  The first obvious clue was the realtime location for my actions were not where they were supposed to be.  Also, appears Google API PHP Client has some issues with PHP7.4FastCGI.

So if you took the time to read ... check your VPN settings if you are getting an abnormal amount of NOT SETS in your GA data.

Begs the question ... with the increase in companies providing VPN services out of the box, that renders some of the tracking a moot point.

LarryG